# Flutter. How do I make a pop-up menu with my widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, menu, popup

How is it here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrqqH.png)

I want to add a widget to the menu without processing a click

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oiuw.png)
My attempts have led to this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is Good if you using Column and you wanna min size for that you have to set main axis size to min
I hope That Will Work